# Centos Stream 9 boot iso stuck during kickstart

Tags: centos, kickstart, packer, anaconda

I am trying to install a Centos Stream 9 boot iso on my mac M1 via VMware Fusion. I already solved a lot of issues that were preventing me to start installation. Now I get to the installation (I am using packer and a kickstart file) but it gets stuck on 'Checking storage configuration'. When checking the logs I see following errors:

[Screenshot of grep through logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xOvTm.png)

Sorry for the screenshot but I can't seem to copy paste the errors from my VM.

When searching for these errors I think the 404 is the root cause because no packages will be able to be installed because of this error. However, I tried to change this 'base repo' through the boot command:

```
"boot_command": [
    "c<wait>",
    "linux /images/pxeboot/vmlinuz inst.stage2=hd:LABEL=CentOS-Stream-9-BaseOS-aarch64 ro ",
    "inst.text biosdevname=0 net.ifnames=0 console=tty0 acpi=off ",
    "inst.repo=https://mirror.netsite.dk/epel/9/Everything/aarch64/ ",
    "inst.addrepo=test,http://fedora.cu.be/epel/9/Everything/aarch64/ ",
    "inst.ks=http://{{ .HTTPIP }}:{{ .HTTPPort }}/ks-{{user `aem_runmode`}}.cfg<enter><wait>",
    "initrd /images/pxeboot/initrd.img<enter>",
    "boot<enter><wait>"
  ],
```

And in my kickstart file:

```
repo --name="base" --baseurl=https://mirror.netsite.dk/epel/9/Everything/aarch64/
url --url https://mirror.netsite.dk/epel/9/Everything/aarch64/
cdrom
lang en_US.UTF-8
keyboard us
network --bootproto=dhcp --noipv6 --onboot=on --device=eth0
rootpw --plaintext vagrant
```

None of these repo's seem to be picked up however. This is my first experience with packer/kickstart/Anaconda so I don't really know what else I can check/try.